# boost::asio UDP how to receive messages on Windows?

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

I have two classes UDPSender and UDPReceiver.
Senarios:
(1)It works when I run UDPSender in QNX and UDPReceiver in Linux.
(2)It doesn't work when I run UDPSender in QNX and UDPReceiver in WindowsXP.(But I see UDP datagrams using Wireshark, meaning Sender is working as in Senario(1))
(3)It partially works in Windows.
    i) if I use Sender sending UDP messages to 127.0.0.1, Receiver can get messages
    ii) if I use Sender sending UDP messages to 192.168.1.137(local address in the network), Receiver can NOT receive.

My question is:

How can I get Receiver working on Windows?

---

some code:

```
UDPReceiver::UDPReceiver( boost::asio::io_service& service, unsigned short port )
: m_service( service ),
  m_socket( service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port)),
  m_peerEndpoint(),
  m_buffer(),
  m_messageReceipient()
{
}

void UDPReceiver::SetMessageReceipient( const boost::function<void(const char*, unsigned int)>& r )
{
     m_messageReceipient = r;
}

void UDPReceiver::Start()
{
    m_socket.async_receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer, m_buffer.size()), m_peerEndpoint,
        boost::bind( &UDPReceiver::HandleReceived, shared_from_this(),
                          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void UDPReceiver::Stop()
{
    m_socket.close();
}

void UDPReceiver::HandleReceived( const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytesReceived )
{
    assert( !m_messageReceipient.empty() );
    if( error ) {
       LOG( Comms, Error, "UDPReceiver:" << error.message() );
    }
    else {
        m_messageReceipient( &m_buffer.front(), bytesReceived );
        m_socket.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer, m_buffer.size()), m_peerEndpoint,
            boost::bind( &UDPReceiver::HandleReceived, shared_from_this(),
                          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

Comment: in Senario(3), I also tried initialize udp socket with local address, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably being blocked by the Windows Firewall.

Comment: after talking to our network support, it's very likely. But the stupid corp laptop doesn't allow me to configure or see anything. I'll try my colleagues laptop(with Windows 7) and see. thanks.

Comment: It is working on my colleague's laptop(windows 7)! his firewall is manageable. Problem solved, stupid me! Thank you!!